# Strange R markdown error message when knitting the document

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Since moving to R version 4 from 3.6, I've gotten a number of error messages such as the one below when trying to knit my Rmd file. It is always associated with calling a ggplot object created within a script.

```
Error in identicalUnits(x) : 
  old version of unit class is no longer allowed
Calls: <Anonymous> ... guide_gengrob.axis -> draw_axis -> unit.c -> identicalUnits
Execution halted
```

I found the beginnings of an answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067331/cant-plot-ggplot2-objects-created-with-r-3-x-into-r-4-x-imported-from-a-rds-fil) but I'm not loading an RDS file. Rather I'm generating the code from a script. What confuses me is that the script run without issue. When I run the individual code chunks in R Markdown, the plot appears. Yet when the document as a whole is knitted, the error is returned.

The code for the plot uses `geom_point`. The only other point of note is that the data set is large (>300,000 rows).

Any ideas why this is happening? My first guess is that it is down to the large number of data points and this disrupts the knit. Should I just call on the plot image from file in this instance rather than regenerating?

Comment: "Any ideas why this is happening? My first guess is that it is down to the large number of data points and this disrupts the knit. Should I just call on the plot image from file in this instance rather than regenerating?" If that's your assumption, why don't you just plot with `head()`? Did you update all your packages? The error message suggests that you have a problem with package versions

Comment: restart R, update grid. Update ggplot2. When knitting you are using a fresh environment, so you would expect different behaviour depending which packages are loaded, which objects you have in your environment etc.

Comment: ah, and I'd also update knitr. Bascially, update everything.

Comment: All packages are up to date.

This is part of an R-project I wasn't involved with. I think the problem is arising from one of the R scripts being `sourced` to within the document, but I haven't pinned it down just yet.